# Which class's object is a?

Tags: java

Here i make an object a.foo();
which class's object is a?

```
class A {
      int b;
}

class B extends A {
    public void foo() { }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        A a = new B();
        a.foo();  
    }

}
```

Comment: That won't compile.

Comment: `a.foo()` is not an object it is method invocation. Also your code wont compiles because `A` have no `foo` method.

Comment: sorry my mistake, but here A a = new B(); which class;s object is a?

Comment: isn't A a = new B();  an object of class B referred to a reference variable of type A?

Answer (score 0):

a is an object of class `B` which extends from class `A`, but you store it in the `super-type` `A` so you can't have access to `foo()` method, to call it you have 2 different ways :

**=>** cast to `B`

```
A a = new B();
((B)a).foo();
```

---

**=>** store in `B` type

```
B a = new B();
a.foo();
```